# How VSCODE appoint flutter engine path when excutive "Debug: Attach to Flutter on Device"?

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, adb, flutter-engine

#### background

I want to set breakpoint in dart code by vscode debuging, normaly i can add `configuration.args` like `--local-engine` and `--local-engine-src-path`, unfortunately is that this flutter app must be `andoird.intent.category.DEFAULT`, so that i can just debug it by `attach`.

#### tried

I can excute commond `<flutter_sdk_path> attach -d <adb_client_id> --local-engine=android_debug_arm64 --local-engine-src-path=<flutter_engine_path>` to attach the app and hot reload is working.

#### wish

I want to set breakpoint in code and `ctrl +shift + p` then `Debug: Attach to Flutter on Device`can do it i guess,so how to appoint flutter engine path when excutive "Debug: Attach to Flutter on Device"?

Answer (score 0):

`launch.json` add following configration can allow you set breakpoint, but the `attach` command has no log(so that in DEBUG CONSOLE pannel has no print info)

```
{
    name: "Dart: Attach to Process",
    request: "attach",
    type: "dart",
    observatoryUri: "${command:dart.promptForVmService}",
    args: [
        "--local-engine=android_debug_arm64",
        "--local-engine-src-path=<flutter_engine_path>"
    ]
}
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4PUf.png)